# How to configure syntastic to use build-depends and hs-source-dirs from my test suite in the .cabal file of the package?

Tags: haskell, vim, cabal, syntastic

Syntastic works great in my system with hdevtools and hlint. But if I'm editing a file under a test directory, importing packages that are exclusively under the test-suite configuration of the cabal package, it marks my imports as bogus and tells me to include them in my cabal file. The same problem happens with the hs-source-dir, it only finds the ones under the library or executable directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no silver bullet.  You can either set `g:syntastic_haskell_hdevtools_args` and friends to the proper flags for your project, or write a wrapper script similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/lcd047/7796203) and point `g:syntastic_haskell_hdevtools_exec` to it.  Syntastic has no built-in support for looking at cabal files.